# "All the more so" - correct use:

Tags: expressions, word-usage, phrase-usage

Is this sentence correct:

"If this was true fifty years ago, it must be all the more so in modern times"

Did I use the expression "all the more so" correctly in this sentence?

Thanks

Comment: Yes: no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is acceptable usage.

In this case "so" is standing in for "true".

You are in effect saying "it must be truer now than it was 50 years ago".

Of course, the reader would probably expect a reason! Consider also whether it's semantically correct for the argument you're making to say something is somewhat true at one point and more true at another point.

Comment: Thanks user52889- that's what I meant to say. In fact, the justification for this statement appears in the previous paragraph, so this sentence is effectively summarizing and underlining this observation.'